# What does 斜め mean here?

Tags: meaning

> 朱実{あけみ}は、からかって、雉子{きじ}のような迅{はし}こい足で、先に山道を降りかけたが、急に顔いろを変えて、立ちすくんだ。中腹の林を**斜め**に、のそのそと大股に歩いて来る男があった。｛宮本武蔵（1935年–1939年、朝日新聞連載、吉川英治）｝

Does 斜め refer to him walking up the hill, or walking diagonally uphill (small picture to illustrate)? Is it ambigious?

[image: http://i.imgur.com/dx6Se9m.png]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would have to mean walking ***diagonally uphill toward*** Akemi, who had just started her descent.

No other interpretation of that sentence would be natural.